# Why won't listfunction iterate through urls?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that opens a url, finds a name in a certain line, and saves it. Then it should find the url in the same line as the name, open it, and find the name + url in the same line # as the previous page. It should do this 4 times.

I can't get it to iterate through the new url parameter. It keeps returning the same name and url. What is going wrong here? Thanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
import ssl
linklist = list()
namelist = list()
linelist = list()
count = 0
listposition = int(input("Please enter list position: "))
goodnamelist = list(["Fikret"])
nexturl = "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html"
def listfunction(url):
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    #Allows reading of HTTPS pages
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    linelist = soup('a')
    for line in linelist:
        #Creates list of lines in webpage:
        linklist.append(re.findall("(http://.+)\"", str(line)))
        #Creates list of names in line:
        namelist.append(re.findall(">(.+)</a>", str(line)))
    #Creates list of names in the designated user-input position:
    goodnamelist.append(namelist[listposition][0])
    nexturl = linklist[listposition][0]
    return nexturl
while (count < 4):
    nexturl = listfunction(nexturl)
    print(listfunction(nexturl))
    count += 1
    print(nexturl)
    continue
print(linelist)
print(linklist)
print(namelist)
print(nexturl)
print(goodnamelist)
print(listfunction(nexturl))
```

Comment: you don't need to use `re` to get your desire data, bs4 offer you ways to get those easily, `line["href"]` will give you the link and `line.get_text()` gets you the name, and if you don't need to save all the list of names and links, you can go directly to the one you want by `line = soup("a")[listposition]`

Comment: a better way to iterate a given number of times is by looping over a range like this `for _ in range(number_of_loops): ...`, here `_` is a little convention for a throw away variable, this way you don't have to worry about increasing counter

Comment: "I can't get it to iterate through the new url parameter. It keeps returning the same name and url" What happens when you call the function? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually set `nexturl` in `listfunction()`. Therefore the method just returns the same initial global variable every time.

Comment: I accidentally took that line out but it has the exact same problem with it in

Comment: It is the same with `listposition` and `linklist`. Both dont actually change in the method, you just append to `linklist` which has no effect. I'm not sure if you intended to clear `linklist`on every run?

Comment: That was what I wasn't catching. Thanks so much, I upvoted but it says it doesn't show publicly until I have 15 reputation.

Comment: @ArinSpanner You can accept the answer though. That's actually more important than voting.